# Access the return object from an observable 'synchronously'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is there a way to access the 'payload' of an observable directly, and have it resolve later, rather than having to subscribe?

For example, I know we can do this..

```
export class RecordService
{
   fetchRecordFromServer():Observable<Record>
   {
       return http.get().pipe(map(result => return new Record())); // equivalent
   }  
}


export class MyComponent
{
  public record:Record = null;
  constructor(private recordService:RecordService) 
  {
     this.userService.fetchRecordFromServer().subscribe( record => 
     {
        this.record = record;
     }); 
  }
  getRecordName():string
  {
     return this.record? this.record.name || "";
  }
}
```

I was just wondering if there is a shorthand way to do something like this

```
export class MyComponent
{
  public record:Observable<Record>;
  constructor(private recordService:RecordService) 
  {
     this.record = this.userService.fetchRecordFromServer();
  }

  getRecordName():string
  {
     return this.record? this.record.name || "";
  }

}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I am asking, but I think what I'm after is the idea that a value can be assigned from an Observable of type , and will resolve when the Observable fires, and can be treated as if it was an instance of  all along.

Maybe promises can do this, or maybe it's a really stupid question. I just feel like I want to say 'set this variable to be an instance of  which will be instantiated at some point soon, but you can try to use it safely straight away, and because the observable is of type  it will treat it as that type...

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use subscribe or what your exact use case is for `this.record` in terms of the view or similar? Are you trying to avoid multiple HttpClient calls? Are you trying to render `this.record` in the template and encounter errors when it's undefined?

Comment: You can use await keyword , but you have to convert observable to a promise

Comment: documentation by Ben Lesh https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - I am not using it in the template. The thinking behind my question is to avoid hundreds of subscribes. For example, I have a large enterprise app which needs to get the user's name repeatedly. I can use a 'hot' observable, and have everything subscribe to that, but it feels really clunky. And the async pipe works fine so long as I only want to use the user name in the UI. I just wondered if there was some other option to Observables/Promises which I have missed.. but looks like probably not.

Answer (score 1):

I think by the code you've added that what you're trying to do is tie the UI directly to a hot observable. You can use an Async pipe to do that:
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-impure-asyncpipe):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-message',
  template: `
      <h2>Async Hero Message and AsyncPipe</h2>
     <p>Message: {{ message$ | async }}</p>
     <button (click)="resend()">Resend</button>`,
})
export class HeroAsyncMessageComponent {
  message$: Observable < string > ;

  private messages = [
    'You are my hero!',
    'You are the best hero!',
    'Will you be my hero?'
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.resend();
  }

  resend() {
    this.message$ = interval(500).pipe(
      map(i => this.messages[i]),
      take(this.messages.length)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm not actually using it in the UI. I think that's the point I am making badly. I am looking for the equivalent of the async pipe but in the code itself. So I can say 'this will be a User() but it won't get here for a while, but when it does,, use the first and last name. I know subscribe will do exactly that, but I was wondering if there was a 'cleverer' way of doing it like async does in the UI

Comment: Ah ok. `subscribe` is effectively what's happening in the async pipe. When you have something asynchronous you'll need to set up a callback to handle it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `async` pipe in the template so that there is no *subscribe* usage inside the component.

```
export class MyComponent
{
    public record$: Observable<Record>;
    constructor(private recordService:RecordService) 
    {
        this.record$ = this.userService.fetchRecordFromServer();
    }

    getRecordName(record: Record):string
    {
        return record ? record.name : "";
    }
}
```

In the template

```
   <h1>{{getRecordName(records$ | async)}}</h1>
```